# Existence of 'best' and 'worst' lottery

Tags: expected-utility, uncertainty

How can **'the best and worst lotteries exist when the set of outcome is finite and the rational preference relation satisfies independence axiom'** be proven?

Comment: And have you considered accepting the answer to your [previous question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20898/axiomatic-bargaining-kalai-smorodinsky-and-nash-solutions-coincide)?

Comment: @denesp: Since this is not an elementary question, it is conceivable that the OP genuinely does not even know how to start approaching it. In light of this consideration, I've provided a hint, though not a full answer, on how to start thinking about the question.

Comment: @HerrK. I would not characterize your answer as "not a full answer", but perhaps I am wrong. Anyway, you have every right to do as you see fit.

Comment: How to do this using induction? I have read in my textbook that gives a hint about using induction on the size of support of p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hint

Let $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ be the set of outcomes. Without loss of generality, let $1\succsim 2\succsim\cdots\succsim N$. Let $\mathbf e_i$ denote the degenerate lottery that assigns probability $1$ on outcome $i$ and $0$ on the rest. Note that any lottery $L=(p_1,\dots,p_N)$ can be written as a compound lottery $p_1\mathbf e_1+\cdots+p_N\mathbf e_N$.

Since lottery $\mathbf e_i$ amounts to getting outcome $i$ for sure, we must have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf e_1\succsim \mathbf e_2\succsim \cdots \succsim \mathbf e_N.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Successively applying the independence axiom to $(1)$, you'll obtain $\mathbf e_1$ as (one of) the best lottery and $\mathbf e_N$ as (one of) the worst.